# restore transmission-daemon status and list from broken ubuntu install

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

today i lost one of my vm's (the disk image refuses to boot but is still accessible).

given the age of the install i decided i would just go with a fresh install.

i have restored almost everything, but transmission-daemon has lost its list of completed/in-progress torrents.

i copied the contents of the resume and torrents folders from both /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info and /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission folders and have restarted transmission, but nothing has shown up at all.

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer when i tried to begin a new torrent.

The permissions on the old installation had become incorrect and had been marked as owned by cups-pk-helper:whoopsie.

changing the permissions for the directories and files to debian-transmission:debian-transmission fixed the issue.